# what is default username password for Azure WebApp MySQL in App

Tags: mysql, azure, phpmyadmin, azure-webapps

Created WebApp with MySQL in App, but tried clicking on Manage un MySQL in APP blade, prompt for username and password.

Is there default username and password or where can i find the credentials.

[image]

Comment: when you create the app it should be there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The connection string of MySQL (ClearDB), please set in the following format.

```
Database=DBNAME;Data Source=MYSQLHOST;User Id=USERID;Password=PASSWD
```

You can get the database's credentials by using FTP to navigate to the

```
/data/mysql/MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini file.
```

Comment: Thanks it did worked. How can i force phpmyadmin for username password, instead of having them in connection string.

Comment: you should raise a new question for that

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (almost 2 years later)

This happens when you click "Manage" to open phpMyAdmin while the website isn't running.

Just browser to your site to wake it up, then try again